# Hm, cannot call javascript function

Tags: javascript, django

Why this not works:

I have main.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some_url"></script>
.
.
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="Foo()">Foo</a></li>
```

Function Foo is located in external javascript file. With this code I cannot call function but if I put that external js into main.html it works. Where is problem? I guess it's something stupid :)

### NEW UPDATE

Well I'm using Django framework and external files are loaded using django static directive:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'st_forms/main.js' %}"></script>
```

function is called like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="goForm('RHJ6YXZh')">Form</a></li>
```

and external main.js file (the whole file):

```
function goForm(formCode)
{
    alert("entered");
}
```

I hope this is enough...

Path to main.js is rendered successfully to "/static/st_forms/main.js" and it is accessible by browser.

Comment: *Where is problem?* <-- Path, Hm

Comment: when i see source code in main.html (right click on page->view source code in firefox) and click on url file is opened and it's ok

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: Did u refer the required js file ?

Comment: I never used console :). How to use it?

Comment: @milandjukic88 In most browsers, hit F12

Comment: Well, the same, firebug opens external file

Comment: @milandjukic88 No no, that's not what we need. You have to look at the console output and then click on the element. If there's something wrong, a message should pop up in the console.

Comment: Oh i see. Console says "ReferenceError: Foo is not defined"

Comment: @milandjukic88 Then we need more code to see what's wrong. What you posted is not enough. Show us more of the HTML (so we know where you load the script, where your link is, the real src of the script, etc.) and the contents of your external Javascript file.

Comment: I cannot believe why this not works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably adding your function `Foo` after the `HTML` is loaded, on `window load`, or `document ready`...

Look at this example:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3HyEZ/)**

```
<script>
    function foo() {
        alert("Foo called!");
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        function bar() {
            alert("Bar called!");
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="foo()">Foo</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="bar()">Bar</a>
```

On click `Foo` is called and `Bar` is not.

Answer (score 0):

try:
    `onclick="Foo()">Foo</a></li>`
instead of original:
    `onClick="Foo()"`

lowercase 'onclick'.

Comment: Please try to elaborate what this does.